# Adding events to an interface / implementation

Tags: c#, events, interface

Know this has been asked before, however my question is slightly different.

I have an interface:

**IEmailDispatcher**

It looks like this:

```
public interface IEmailDispatcher
{
    void SendEmail(string[] to, string fromName, string fromAddress, string subject, string body, bool bodyIsHTML, Dictionary<string, byte[]> Attachments);
}
```

As a bit of background:

I have a static EmailDispatcher class that has the method:
    SendEmail(string[] to, string fromName, string fromAddress, string subject, string body, bool bodyIsHTML, Dictionary Attachments);

This, throught IoC, then loads the relevant IEmailDispatcher implementation, and calls that method.

My applications can then simply call EmailDispatcher.SendEmail(.........

I want to add events to it, for example OnEmailSent, OnEmailFail etc...
So that each implementation can handle successes and failures of sending emails, and log them accordingly.

How would I go about doing this?

Or, is there a better way?

At the moment, I'm using a "BasicEmailDispatcher" that basically uses the System.Net namespaces, creates a MailMessage, and sends it.

In the future, I will create another class, that handles mail differently... adds it to a sql db table for reporting etc.... and so will handle the OnEmailSent events differently to the BasicEmailDispatcher

Answer (score 3):

It looks like trying to fit everything into the static class is making you do awkward things here (specifically, implementing [the template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) using a static class). If callers (applications) only need to know about the `SendEmail` method, that's the only thing that should be in the interface.

If that is indeed the case, you can just make your base dispatcher class implement the template pattern:

```
public class EmailDispatcherBase: IEmailDispatcher {
    // cheating on the arguments here to save space
    public void SendEmail(object[] args) {
        try {
            // basic implementation here
            this.OnEmailSent();
        }
        catch {
            this.OnEmailFailed();
            throw;
        }
    }
    protected virtual  void OnEmailSent() {}
    protected virtual  void OnEmailFailed() {}
}
```

More complex implementations would each inherit from `BasicEmailDispatcher` (and therefore implement `IEmailDispatcher`) and override one or both of the virtual methods to provide success or failure behavior:

```
public class EmailDispatcherWithLogging: EmailDispatcherBase {
    protected override OnEmailFailed() {
        // Write a failure log entry to the database
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement this-
Where does my static class fit in? The "entry point" from the callers...?

For example, I have BasicEmailDispatcher, DummyEmailDispatcher... do they still implement IEmailDispatcher? or BaseEmailDispatcher...

Comment: Also - what causes each EmailSent and EmailFailed event will be different in each implementation....

Comment: Sorry - I misunderstood your requirements somewhat! In the process of revising my answer, I've tried to clarify it a bit too. As for your static class, it's really a separate issue - you can keep using it as you've been doing. (Though I recommend reading around on StackOverflow about singletons and dependency injection!)

Answer (score 2):

```
public interface IEmailDispatcher
{
    event EventHandler EmailSent;
    void SendEmail(string[] to, string fromName, string fromAddress, string subject, string body, bool bodyIsHTML, Dictionary<string, byte[]> Attachments);
}
```

For more details, look [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ak9w5846%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Is this the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Add the events to your interface :

```
public interface IEmailDispatcher
{
    void SendEmail(string[] to, string fromName, string fromAddress, string subject, string body, bool bodyIsHTML, Dictionary<string, byte[]> Attachments);
    event EmailSentEventHandler EmailSent;
    event EmailFailedEventHandler EmailFailed;
}
```

And in your static class, use explicit event accessors to subscribe to the events of the actual implementation :

```
public static class EmailDispatcher
{
    public event EmailSentEventHandler EmailSent
    {
        add    { _implementation.EmailSent += value; }
        remove { _implementation.EmailSent -= value; }
    }

    public event EmailFailedEventHandler EmailFailed
    {
        add    { _implementation.EmailFailed += value; }
        remove { _implementation.EmailFailed -= value; }
    }
}
```