# Event handling with simple dependency injection and decoupling

Tags: php, events, dependency-injection, event-handling

I'm developing a MVC framework for educational purposes. Now I'm stuck with how should I handle events in my framework.

The closest answer I was looking for was [Adding events to an interface / implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975922/adding-events-to-an-interface-implementation) but it doesn't say anything about the injection part.

My question is, are both approaches good enough? are they decoupled?

The language is PHP but treat it as pseudo-code.

This **first example** is kind of C# approach. `ClassA` is injected with `Kernel` class, and it is its own responsibility to subscribe to the event.

```
class Kernel{
    public $onInit      = new EventHandler();
    public $onTerminate = new EventHandler();
    public function __construct(){
    }
    public function boot(){
        //...dosomething
        $this->onInit->raise($this, new EventArgs());
        $this->onTerminate->raise($this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
class ClassA{
    public function __construct($kernel){
        $kernel->onInit->add(array($this,'onKernelInit'));
    }
    public function onKernelInit($sender, $args){
        $this->doSomething($sender);
    }
    public function doSomething(Kernel $kernel){}
}
```

With this second approach, there is an intermediate class which is responsible for subscribing to the event. `ClassAListener` is injected with `ClassA` and `KernelEventDispatcher`.

```
class Kernel{
  public $dispatcher;
  public function __construct(KernelEventDispatcher $dispatcher){
    $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher;
  }
  public function boot(){
    //do something...
    $this->dispatcher->raiseInit($this, new EventArgs());
    $this->dispatcher->raiseTerminate($this, new EventArgs());
  }
}
class ClassAListener{
  public function __construct(ClassA $classA, KernelEventDispatcher $dispatcher){
    $this->classA = $classA;
    $dispatcher->onInit(array($this, 'onKernelInit'));
  }
  public function onKernelInit($sender, $args){
    $classA->doSomething($sender);
  }
}
```

I'm leaning towards the second approach as it is much cleaner, but I'm not sure if it is 'going the right way' (handling events).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: +1 on the second approach as well. First approach creates a unpublished dependency on EventHandler... is this framework going to be available to the masses or for a private audiance?

Comment: Right now the main objective of my framework is to learn new things (which I have learned a lot; design patterns, dependency injection, etc.). I want to make it open source but depends on how satisfied I am with the result (code). And thanks for your input.

Comment: make it open source... let others contribute... it will only extend the learning...

Comment: I will probably to do it, since it's hard to find simple php frameworks that follows good programming habits.

Comment: If you decide to, post the details here ... you've gotten my interest.

Comment: It's not finished yet. I've decided the overall design of the framework though, and I'm currently converting the old code (old design) to the new design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the second approach is better because the first approach creates a dependency on an implementation of EventHandler that is not immediately obvious and that would be difficult to extend or replace.